# Create Lag variable with three conditions

Tags: sas

-I need a lead variable based on 3 conditions. IF variable RoaDLM has a number and IF the Co_ID is the same as the lag(co_id) and IF CEO = lag(ceo), I need a lead variable: Lead1
-i sort descending to create lag variable
-Every thing else should be '.'
-here is my code:

```
data RoaReg;
set RoaReg;
    by CO_ID descending fyear;
    if RoaDlm ne 0 and Co_ID = lag(CO_ID)  and ceo=ceo then
    Lead1 = lag(ROA); 
    else if RoaDlm= 0 then
    Lead1='.';
run;
```

-Anyway, this does not work. Thanks!

Comment: Can  you include some sample, fake data, that illustrates your issue? You're using lead/lag so not sure what you're actually trying to do here and some data will clarify and allow us to test a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Theres a couple of issues with your code.

1. Do not use the same data set name in the SET and DATA statements. This is a recipe for errors that are difficult to debug.
2. Lag() cannot be calculated conditionally, use it always and set to missing when necessary.

   ```
   data RoaReg2;
   set RoaReg;
   by CO_ID descending fyear;
   Lead1 = lag(ROA); 
   if  RoaDlm= 0 then call missing (lead1); 
   run;
   ```

This is the correct version of your code, or my best guess. Providing sample data would help for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understood, you need a lead variable based on few conditions - two being lagged value of the variables.

You don't have a `lead` function in SAS, as per my knowledge. You can use `proc expand` for that purpose. And, you did not mention about the variable for which you want a lead - so, I am assuming it to be a variable named **ROA**.

So, here is my best guess/interpretation of what you want.

```
data RoaReg_lead;
merge RoaReg RoaReg(keep=ROA rename=(ROA=LeadROA) firstobs=2); /*merged the same table with only the ROA variable, and read the values from 2nd observation | can't use by variables in order to do so*/
Lag_co_id=lag(co_id); /*creating lagged values*/
Lag_ceo=lag(ceo);

/*conditions*/
if (RoaDLM ne . and RoaDLM>0) and co_id=Lag_co_id and ceo=Lag_ceo then
    Lead1=LeadROA;

drop Lag_co_id Lag_ceo LeadROA; /*You can keep the vars to do a manual check*/
run;
```

Otherwise, providing a sample table of your data (have and want) would be very helpful.